# CSS background-blend-mode not working on Samsung S9

Tags: css, samsung-galaxy

Using ´background-blend-mode´, it works on most mobile devices and browsers, but on the *Samsung S9* it doesn't.

S9:

[image]

Others:

[image]

My CSS code:

```
  .home-section-hero {
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it's about chrome version. Check it, please.

Comment: What version of chrome is it?

Comment: @SergioAndrade We checked it on 2 S9 devices, from 2 different countries and both had the issue. Kind of improbable that both devices won't have the latest version.

Comment: @IPAddress 73.0.3683.90.

Comment: I got the same one on my Huawei and it works.

Comment: Where's the CSS for the background images/color? If they're not applied to the same element then background-blend-mode won't work.

Comment: Why it does works everywhere except the Samsung device?

Comment: I just checked and if I put the "Desktop version" on mobile, it works, so when it get the mobile design, it doesn0t.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with background-blend-mode. In you first screenshot, it's the background-image property that isn't loading. If background-blend-mode wasn't working you would still see the gradient and polygon image.

Comment: @jdfink So yeah, why it doesn't loads on the Samsung S9 device, but in others it works?

Comment: I am having an identical issue I think. Can you see if your s9 has the same issue with this question and code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245650/css-background-blend-mode-not-working-in-chrome-mobile