# CSS background-blend-mode not working in chrome mobile with viewport meta tag

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-blend-mode

Most blend modes do not work in chrome mobile - I have been able to get 'screen', and 'overlay' to work, but not ones like multiply, darken, exclusion, etc. Does anyone know if this has to do with perhaps the s9's gpu architecture being incompatible here?

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/thewebkid/pen/PMWZLW)

Here is a simple example with screen shots:

```
<style>
.blended-gradient{
  background-blend-mode:exclusion, normal;
  background:linear-gradient(black 0, white 50%,  black 100%),
    radial-gradient(black 0, white 70%, black 70.1%);  
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
</style>
<div class="blended-gradient"></div>
```

In chrome desktop, I see a nice metallic looking ball:

[image: chrome desktop]

In chrome android, I see failure:

[image: failure]

Would love to know if this is a known issue or if there are any workarounds. Please note that I am in a chrome-only environment, so I am not as concerned with other browsers currently.

### Update 1

It appears this may be a Samsung s9 issue as someone else is seeing this sporadically on s9s since April 2019. I have only tested on my personal s9. Requesting desktop version of site solves it, but that does not help end users. [CSS background-blend-mode not working on Samsung S9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500046/css-background-blend-mode-not-working-on-samsung-s9)

### Update 2

Removing the meta name=viewport tag fixes the issue and everything renders fine. This is obviously not a feasable workaround, so I am hoping a chrome developer sees this. Will post a bug.

Comment: What version of Chrome android are you using ? it works from version 75 and above

Comment: check this: https://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode and see your version

Comment: I am on v75. I think this might have something to do with the s9 specifically. See this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500046/css-background-blend-mode-not-working-on-samsung-s9

Comment: Also, this feature is not new. It has been implemented for years if you look carefully at caniuse data - see the chrome ver 46 issues back in 2015 for example.

Comment: Been messing with your example (PC only!) and it seems the linear gradient is not painted. Currently I am toying with blend modes and color mixing myself. Maybe using a `div.blended-gradient` and  `div.blended-gradient::after` with `mix-blend-mode` on the `::after` is a workaround?? Works on PC. (Too late at nite for me to test on Android)

Comment: Checked workaround anyway on Android 9 (Samsung J4+, cheaper sister). Stupid Chrome won't even run properly (actually hangs on any site, settings too). Firefox 68 on Android works with workaround, Samsung Internet too (9.2.10.15)

Comment: @RenevanderLende, thanks. I am actually working with sometimes 9 layers and 9 blend modes if you look at my other pens you will see what I mean. So adding pseudos might work for the above, but I am hoping it is perhaps a minor chrome patch because I need to do much, much crazier things here :)

Comment: Please do elaborate on that as I currently am messing with RGB/CYMK/HSL stacking colors on layers (like Photoshop'ish=> very crude) and am making quite some progress with CSS only solutions. Exchange info in chat/mail etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197131/discussion-between-ron-gilchrist-and-rene-van-der-lende).